# The Asbab Al-Nuzul (Historical Background) of Surah 4:157

Tags: quran, prophet-muhammad, islamic-basis, prophet-isa, mecca

Does anyone know the historical background behind 4:157, and if so can you link a source w/ the Arabic? Thanks!

Comment: Could you explain why you expect this verse to have a historical background rather than just being revealed generally to teach people?

Comment: The context of this verse is a Jewish/Christian claim, why should it have a historical background in the time of the prophet Muhammad ()? Not every verse in the qur'an must have a historical background -> sabab an-Nuzul!

Answer (score 1):

For this specific verse no reason for revelation (sabab an-Nuzul) was mentioned in any reliable source or tafsir.